# How to deliver an end user application to the client in vb 6.0

Tags: vb6, installation

I created forms in vb 6.0 for eg.login, customer details, etc. So just wanted to know how to deliver those forms to the client. Is it in the form of application or need to install visual basics 6.0 in client's computer in order to make the application run?
Please help me in this and if I need to create an application please let me how how to do that. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If you built your forms without having to add extra Components or References, you might be able to simply deliver an EXE. To build an EXE, select "Make (your project name).exe..." from the File menu. This will generate an EXE you can give to your client. If they get errors trying to run the EXE, their system might need to have some VB6 components (DLLs, OCXs, etc) installed which you can handle by providing them with an Installer.

You can use the **Microsoft Visual Studio Installer 1.1** to create an Installer (MSI) and deliver that to your client. It should have everything your EXE needs to run properly.

Finding Microsoft Visual Studio Installer 1.1 *can be difficult*. It's not available from Microsoft anymore but here's a link to the Setup1.exe and Setup2.exe files on my Google Drive:

[Microsoft Visual Studio Installer 1.1](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1CSms_TgCJBlEV6NNZVhKmg2NIKiGpGbk)

Once you have that installed, you can create a new Installer project using your project's VBP file. It will read the Components and References you use and bundle them into an MSI for you.

You can also create an Installer using **Visual Studio 2019** (Community Edition is free) and download the [Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Projects](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioClient.MicrosoftVisualStudio2017InstallerProjects) extension. You will have to manually add the files your project uses (EXE, DLLs, OCXs, etc) but this will work if you can't download VSI 1.1.

Comment: Although the link works, the Setup1.exe and setup2.exe file links appear not to...

Comment: Updated the link to Google Drive. Not ideal but just trying to make the installer available for the sake of helping @Ryan_carter out with his deployment.

Answer (score 2):

The "official" way to do this is by using the (deeply flawed, but still workable for a simple application such as this appears to be) Package and Deployment Wizard.  This will compile you application, and create a .cab file with all of the necessary added files (OCXs, etc.).  It also creates an installer program that will automatically install these on the end user's machine, in a fairly friendly manner.

The PDW should have been automatically installed along with the reset of the Visual Basic 6.0 environment.  (I'm not sure if it was included in non-Professional versions of VB-6, however.)

Comment: And, as Étienne said, if it's really a simple application, without any external references or components, simply distributing the EXE file may be enough.  Every version of Windows from 7 on comes with the Visual Basic 6.0 runtime component pre-installed, so if you make a VB program using only the intrinsic controls (those that are present in the default project), you're done!  Just compile to an EXE file and distribute that.